# Where to ask "too broad" questions?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently posted a question here:

[Enterprise Architecture: Where to put persistence/dbContext management?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/303435/enterprise-architecture-where-to-put-persistence-dbcontext-management)

I'd come here from Stack Overflow specifically because I thought that this was the place for more "broad" questions, yet a comment indicates that this may be too broad still for programmers.stackexchange:

> Any time we venture into "enterprise" decisions, things get too complicated very quickly. I voted to close as "too broad". There are a million reason why any single answer would be incorrect for another project. Even if it feels correct to you, it's not correct in a general sense. Anytime there's no clear-cut correct answer, the question is not a good fit for Programmers.

Is there a place within the SE network for these types of questions, or are they generally frowned upon across the board because they might not tend to have clear cut, correct answers?

Or perhaps some sort of network map to help newbies like myself land in the right areas and conform to the right expectations?

Answer (score 3):

There is no place to questions that are "too broad" on the network. However, I don't think that your question falls into the "too broad" category (at least on an initial reading). I wouldn't worry about one vote.

Comment: Thanks - still new to SO/SE and trying to figure out what's acceptable and go with the flow.  Unfortunately, many questions I have don't seem to have highly straightforward answers...